# Parallel Commands no longer working in script?

Tags: parallel-ssh

I've made a script that goes through and updates our Linux servers. It was working just fine for the past month or so. But just this morning I now receive the error:

`Could not open hosts file: No such file or directory`

I'm at a loss here because nothing has changed with the directory of the file and it was working just fine with no issue up until this morning after the weekend. It's not a crazy big deal it was just nice to be able to just run a script on Monday mornings but I'm curious as to what may have caused this to start occuring?

If I input the commands one by one in terminal there is no error and everything works just fine. Why is it that when I have it setup as a script it no longer wants to work?

Here are the commands:

```
parallel-ssh -i -h ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt uptime
parallel-ssh -h ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt -t 100000000 sudo apt update
parallel-ssh -h ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt -t 100000000 sudo apt upgrade -y
parallel-ssh -h ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt sudo reboot now
```

I tried changing the location of the file and altering the folder and txt file names. But this did nothing.

Output of

```
ls -l ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt
```

is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ricerit ricerit 138 Dec  1 13:26 /home/ricerit/scripting/linuxhosts.txt
```

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Can you please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt` as the user you're running these commands?

Comment: Just did. I went through and used that full location and now I'm getting new authenticity request? Which is really odd as all my SSH keys are on those machines.

Comment: So I solved it. But uh don't feel like I solved it? All I did was create a new script file and just copy pasted my script and it's no longer an issue whatsoever? I really feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: Are you sure you're running it as `ricerit` in all of your tests?  If you were, for example, running it as `root` then `~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt` would likely point to `/root/scripting/linuxhosts.txt`.

Comment: Yeah I'm running it as ricerit. I'm quite confused over the whole situation.

Comment: It's a good idea to keep track of your edits to the script.  The actions that fixed the issue are consistent with an extra character somehow being inserted into the script where it gives the name of the hosts file.  For example, a carriage return character between the filename and the line feed that Linux/Unix systems have at the end of each line in a text file.  Editing with a Windows text editor can often do this, and a Carriage Return character often won't show itself when you use a simple view command like `cat script-name`.  The copy/paste made a new script without that extra character.

Comment: Try: `tracefile parallel-ssh -i -h ~/scripting/linuxhosts.txt uptime`  (https://codeberg.org/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/tracefile/tracefile). This should list all files it is trying to access. Maybe that will tell you which file it cannot open.